# Group values of a flat associative array by value to generate a 2d array where new rows contain original keys

Tags: php, arrays, grouping, associative-array

I have an array of the form

```
$a = array(
   'a' => 0,
   'b' => 0,
   'c' => 1
);
```

and want an array of the form

```
array(
   0 => array('a','b'),
   1 => array('c')
);
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll just have to use a `foreach`, as `array_flip` will make you lose the duplicates:

```
$b = array();
foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
    $b[$v][] = $k;
}

var_dump($b);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a body-less loop because values are processed before keys in the signature of `foreach()` loop.  Define the `$v` variable, then use that variable as the first level key as you push the original key as a new child element in the result array.  This approach uses one less variable declaration versus the classic "bodied" loop.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5hJsu))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($a as $result[$v][] => $v);    
var_export($result);
```

See also: [Within a foreach() expression, is the value defined before or after the key?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71030746/2943403)

---

Functional iteration is decidedly less elegant: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/pW14f))

```
var_export(
    array_reduce(
        array_keys($a),
        function ($result, $k) use ($a) {
            $result[$a[$k]][] = $k;
            return $result;
        }
    )
);
```